# Very slow MySQL query yet columns are properly indexed

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, explain

```
SELECT DISTINCT journey.id, line.name AS line, getDestination(pattern.section) AS destination, TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(pl2.time))), '%H:%i') AS departure, operator.code AS operator, bus.registration
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
INNER JOIN service ON service.id = journey.service
INNER JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
INNER JOIN line ON line.service = service.id
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
INNER JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = :stop
INNER JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pattern.section AND pl2.sequence < pl.sequence
LEFT JOIN findmybus.bus ON bus.journey_id = journey.id
WHERE journey_day.day = :day AND CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND operator.id = :operator
GROUP BY journey.id, journey.departure
HAVING (TIME_TO_SEC(journey.departure) + SUM(pl2.time)) < 86400
```

Here is the result of an `EXPLAIN` statement prepended to the query:

[image]

Why is this query so slow? I have added indexes to all the columns that are joined in the `ON` clause. It seems like they are not all being used, why might this be?

Results of query: [image]

Comment: simplify the query bit by bit (commenting out or removing query parts and select parts) and compare ... if it is one thing that is slowing it down then you should see a jump. It'll be fun

Comment: Can we see tha actual query being executed. And that GROUP BY appears to nullify your DISTINCT option

Comment: Applying index to all columns is not good idea. can we see real output?

Comment: Possible candidates: getDestination() in select; joins with < instead of = ... but looks like it is doing a lot of work.

Comment: @Justcode I'll screenshot the result set, 1 moment

Comment: @Justcode I have edited the question and added the output

Comment: @Ruskin Can confirm it's not getDestination() as removing it made no change, is there a better way to write the join with a '<'? That is definitely where the problem is as changing it to '=' makes it much faster, though I do need to get the departures that are less than that sequence so can't write it with an '='

Comment: Remove all index apply indexes on a columns which are in a where clause

Comment: It would help if you could post a schema - at a guess, I'd say that patternlink needs an index including section and sequence, in that order.

Comment: No answer, just some remarks: You aggregate data (by using GROUP BY), so result lines are per se distinct. Remove the DISTINCT keyword. Maybe this even saves the dbms some work (though it shouldn't). You group by journey. Per journey there can be many lines, so what line.name do you want to get? So far you get a random match. There can also be many busses per journey, so what bus.registration do you want to get? Again you get a random match with your query.

Comment: Joel, sometimes you cannot get queries any faster without refactoring the database layout. How often is this run? Every page load / request on the find my bus site, or only occasionally. Sometimes you may need to run a cron job to create a flat-file / generated table with the data you want, then use that cached version to supply info to the web page - massively improving performance. How often does the data change? If it is live bus tracking then you may need to refactor.

Comment: @Ruskin This is run very frequently when a user requests to see departure times from a specific bus stop. I'm not sure what you've stated would be 100% necessary, I think it's just that I haven't written the query very well. Would you mind if I added you on the likes of Skype just to ask you a few more questions to make sure I don't need to do what you've stated? I'd really appreciate your help and I won't take much of your time! My username is jskidd3

Comment: A specific bus stop? I don't see any where criteria on a specific bus stop in your query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I think I'll need to repost this question with a schematic. But the bus stop is in the 'pl' pattern_link JOIN in the ON clause. You should see ':stop'

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that.

Comment: What's the storage engine being used?

Comment: What's your definition of `so slow`?

Answer (score 0):

As to using indexes: This pays when you access a small part of your data. From a look at your query, I would have guessed the dbms to start with the journey_day table. There are probably thousands of days in that table, so limiting it to one particular day should result in a small percentage to select from the table.

But then, how many journeys would that be, or more precisely: what percentage of the journey table will be relevant? The dbms has to estimate this to decide for or against index usage here. And this goes for every table.

You *can* try to speed things up by moving the journey_day criteria into an exists clause, but to be honest, I don't expect this to help much. MySql is usually best when you simply join, as you are already doing. Anyhow, why not try it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  journey.id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(line.name) AS lines,
  getDestination(pattern.section) AS destination,
  TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(pl2.time))), '%H:%i') AS departure, 
  operator.code AS operator, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(bus.registration) as registrations
FROM journey
INNER JOIN service ON service.id = journey.service AND CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end
INNER JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator AND operator.id = :operator
INNER JOIN line ON line.service = service.id
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
INNER JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = :stop
INNER JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pattern.section AND pl2.sequence < pl.sequence
LEFT JOIN findmybus.bus ON bus.journey_id = journey.id
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM journey_day 
  WHERE journey_day.journey = journey.id 
  AND journey_day.day = :day
)
GROUP BY journey.id
HAVING (TIME_TO_SEC(journey.departure) + SUM(pl2.time)) < 86400;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thorsten. Sadly this didn't speed up the query. I have just tried to change the '<' to a '=' in the `pl2` join and the query now takes 0.2 seconds. Is there any way of re-writing this part of the query to make it do the same thing but without the huge delay in execution? I still need it to be less than but currently as the question states it's just too slow.

Comment: Well, with = it is clear for the dbms that it can quickly find records in an index, with < however it may have muddle its way through many index branches. Do you have a combined index on section + sequence already?